# Can't enter the right data into MySQLi it keeps showing 0 as the data

Tags: php, mysqli

Whenever i entered any data in the PHP page, it keeps adding 0 as the database.
[it says 0 in the mysql table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tBjc0.png)
i'm a new student and i really don't understand where the error is.

1. Here is my PHP and form coding.

   ```
   <form name="Submit" method="post" action="signupconn.php">
   <p>
     <input type="text" name="textfield" id="teachersname">
   </p>
   <p>
     <input type="text" name="textfield2" id="teachersphone">
   </p>
   <p>
     <textarea name="textarea" id="teachersadd"></textarea>
   </p>
   <p>
     <input type="text" name="textfield3" id="teachersic">
   </p>
   <p>
     <input type="text" name="textfield6" id="teachersqualify">
   </p>
   <p><input type="text" name="textfield7" id="classassigned"></p>
   <p>
     <input type="text" name="textfield4" id="teachersusername">
   </p>
   <p>
     <input type="text" name="textfield5" id="teacherspassword">
   </p>
   <p>&nbsp;</p>
   <p><input type="reset" value="Reset">
   <input type="submit" value="Sign Up"></p>
   </form>
   <?php
   $server="localhost"; //host Name
   $username="root"; //Mysql username
   $password=""; //Mysql password
    $dbname="taska_ceria_"; //Database name

    //Creating connection to mysqli.
    $conn=new mysqli($server,$username,$password,$dbname);

     //checking connection

     if($conn->connect_error){
     die("Connection failed" . $conn->connect_error);
     }

     if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
     $teachersname = 
     mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['teachersname']);
     $teachersphone = 
     mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['teachersphone']);$teachersadd 
     = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['teachersadd']);
     $teachersic = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['teachersic']);
     $teachersqualify = 
     mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['teachersqualify']);
     $classassigned = 
     mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['classassigned']);
     $teachersusername = 
     mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['teachersusername']);
     $teacherspassword = 
     mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['teacherspassword']);

      }

    $sql= "INSERT INTO 
    teachersinfo(teachersname,teachersic,teachersphone,teachersadd,
    teachersqualify,classassigned,teachersusername,teacherspassword)  VALUE 
    ('$teachersname','$teachersphone','$teachersadd','$teachersic',
    '$teachersqualify','$classassigned','$teachersusername',
    '$teacherspassword')";

     if($conn->query($sql) === TRUE){
      echo "Record Added Succesfully";
      header("location:body.php");
       }
      else
       {
     echo "Error" . $sql . "<br/>" . $conn->error;
      }
      $conn->close();
      ?>
   ```

   2. When I enteredthe data it says the data has been entered successfully but in the mysql table the content of the data has 0 on every attributes.

3.Please someone help me.

Comment: You are wide open for SQL injection. `real_escape_string` is not safe enough. Since you're using mysqli, take advantage of [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [bind_param](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php). **This will take care of any pesky quoting issues that may occur.**

Comment: The name of the field gets passed through the form, not the id. Change all of the names in your form to be the same as the ids, or at least whatever you're looking for in your PHP script.

Comment: does that mean i have to discard real_escape_string and replace them with prepared statements and bind_param?

Comment: Yes, that would be the safe thing to do.

Answer (score 1):

You have use id as input post,

```
<input type="text" name="textfield" id="teachersname">
```

use teachersname on name field.

```
<input type="text" name="teachersname" id="teachersname">
```

Then it may work properly

Comment: What is *You have use id as input post* supposed to mean?

Comment: He's posted the correct solution - but it's just worded oddly.

Comment: while submitting the form name of input field to passed, not it's id. the id is used in case of javascript,

Comment: i tried just like you suggested but it still doesnt work. it's still the same as before

Comment: Have you change every field??